# Automatic type conversion

Tags: c++, proxy, wrapper

Suppose I have a class like so (Note that this is modeled after the [Method Wrapper](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf) by Stroustrup:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapper
{

  private:

  //This class is implicitly convertable to T&
  struct TempRef 
  { 
     operator T&(); 
     T& operator()(); 
     ~TempRef();   //Executes clean up code
  };
  struct TempPtr 
  { 
    T* operator T->(); 
    ~TempPtr();  //Executes clean up code
  };

  public:
  TempRef operator*();
  TempPtr operator->();

};
```

The goal for this class is for it to act like a pointer to `T`:

And it works in some cases:

```
Wrapper<thing> var;
var->foo();
```

The problem comes when I want to use it as wrapper for an integral type:

```
Wrapper<int> var;
//*var = 12;  //Oops!! Does not work (no automatic conversion)
((int&)(*var)) = 12; //Works but the syntax is a pain
(*var)() = 12;  //Good but still could be better
```

So the question is this:

Is there any way to make the syntax for using `Wrapper` as a wrapper for an integral type the same as a pointer to an integral type, or is that just impossible at the moment?

Comment: It doesn't work any better for a pointer. You're testing two different things. Try assigning to a wrapped pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an assignment operator in `Wrapper`.  Something like

```
Wrapper<T> &operator=(const T &v) {
    /*something to get the T& returned by TempRef::operator T&*/ = v;
    return *this;
}
```

This would then be invoked by `var = 12;`.

Comment: Yes....this is perfect...... Just need to make one for all of the other operators and then it will work perfectly...... Of course only with enable if T has that operation.......